# Can I create a dialog box, when I perform a long click on a text view...?

Tags: android

Thank in advance....
Hi to all,
   I have a requirement to open a dialog box when i perform a long click on a text view. Is it possible if yes how? Can any one help me out from this issue....

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to write on longClick listener for that text box:

```
yourTextBox.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       // add code to open dialog window
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `onLongClickListener` on TextView, and in `onClick()` method in this listener, implement following code,

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure?");
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // here you can add functions
   }
});
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

regist a onlongClickListner on your textView and create a Dialog in the listener

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
            .setMessage(
                    getString(R.string.yourMsg))
            .setPositiveButton(
                    "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

if your don't want to continue process the onClick method or onTouch... return true in the end.(won't execute the code in onClick method)